# Complex Lambda to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have a Lambda expression which is causing 'Multiple values in sequence' ie data duplication it seems.This is the lambda expression  :

```cs
var destinations = this.contentBusiness.GetAllDisplayVersions()
.Where(x => airportDestinations.Any(y => y.DestinationAirport.DestinationGuideId == x.ParentId))
.Select(x => new DestinationViewModel(airportDestinations.Single(y => y.DestinationAirport.DestinationGuideId == x.ParentId), x));
```

Now I need the **corresponding SQL statement** for this.

Comment: It's called linq, lambdas are delegates written in other syntax. Lambda: `(x,y)=>dostuff()` || Linq: `list.Where(something).Select(something)`

Comment: You are instantiating objects (basically, calling object functions)... there is no SQL equivalent to this.

Comment: @Cybȫʁgϟ37 well, that depends an awful lot on what `GetAllDisplayVersions()` returns. If it returns `IEnumerable<DisplayVersion>` or `List<DisplayVersion>` or `DisplayVersion[]`, then: you're right. However, if it returns `IQueryable<DisplayVersion>`, then this could be a fully composable query (assuming it isn't via `.AsQueryable()`). So, to the OP: what does `GetAllDisplayVersions()` return? And how?

Comment: Thank you all,I splitted the expression and debugged,finally identified the duplicate record,thus rectified.

Answer (score 0):

Why not run the SQL Profiler?

- Put a break point on this line.
- On the following line put destinations.AsEnumerable() to force the SQL to be run.
- Run the application.
- When the breakpoint hits run start the profiler trace
- Run to the the AsEnumerable() or equivalent line (i.e. one that will force the SQL to be generated and run against the SQL Server)
- See what the SQL Profiler picked up.